# How to test code dependent on environment variables using JUnit mockito?

Tags: mockito, junit4

I am trying to add import "org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables;" but  getting error This(org.junit.cont....) import  cannot be resolved. I added below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
    <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

any other way to set environment variable using junit mockito.
Can i set the env variable using powermock ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a newer version, like [`1.19.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stefanbirkner/system-rules).

I am not sure when the class was introduced, but its later than `1.2.0`.

**Edit:**
The GitHub list a change date of `May 18, 2018`, so it should be at least 
`1.18.0`.